# Final compiled manifest has screenOrientation not present on my manifest files

Tags: android, android-manifest

My final `AndroidManifest.xml` after it is all merged has a `screenOrientation` that I don't have on my own manifests. The merger blame file has this:

`957-->[:adsmodule] pathtoadsmodule/build/intermediates/library_manifest/googleDebug/AndroidManifest.xml:70:13-36
958            android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

So that is where it is coming from but that file itself doesn't have `screenOrientation` in it, in fact it has this:

```
    <!-- removed screen orientation -->
    <activity
        android:name="some activity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
```

And on my final `AndroidManifest.xml` I see this:

```
    <!-- removed screen orientation -->
    <activity
        android:name="some activity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
```

Even my comment `<!-- removed screen orientation -->` is there but yet it has the `screenOrientation` so I just don't understand what is happening.

If I search the `build` directory of `adsmodule`, I don't find anything with the words `portrait` in it. So where is it getting inserted?

I've cleaned, and cleared cache and invalidated multiple times so I don't think that is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove a property from a lower priority manifest out of your control you can use a Node Marker such as tools:node="remove" in your manifest. This will override the merging heuristics.

In your manifest declare the following:

```
<activity
    android:name="some activity">
      <meta-data android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  tools:node="remove"/>
</activity>
```

This will remove the item screenOrientation from the activity “some activity” from the merged manifest.

Learn more here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#merge_rule_markers

Comment: Thanks, I think that'll be the only solution then.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest merger tool combines all `XML` elements from each file by following some merge heuristics and by obeying merge preferences that you have defined with special `XML` attributes. This page describes how manifest merging works and how you can apply merge preferences to resolve merge conflicts.

The merger tool combines all the manifest files into one file by merging them sequentially based on each manifest file's priority. For example, if you have three manifest files, the lowest priority manifest is merged into the next highest priority, and then that is merged into the highest priority manifest

[image]

I invite you to read more about the [Merge conflict heuristics](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#merge_conflict_heuristics) from the official documentation for a better understanding of what is actually happening in your case

Comment: I understand that but I still don't know where that attribute is coming from, particularly since the final xml has my comment `<!-- removed screen orientation -->` and `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`. Are you saying it is merging the same declaration for that `Activity` from probably the library that activity comes from? In that case, is there a way to make it override it?